# How to static_cast raw pointer to pointer-to-fixed-array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am having trouble with a function that takes a pointer to a fixed array. I have a simple pointer and the compiler will not allow me to `static_cast` it to the pointer-to-array type.

Here's some example code:

```
int main() 
{
    typedef int (*Arr3)[3];

    int a[3] = {1,2,3};
    int* p = &a[0];

    Arr3 b = static_cast<Arr3>(p);
}
```

Error message:

```
prog.cpp:11:10: error: static_cast from 'int *' to 'Arr3' (aka 'int (*)[3]') is not allowed
Arr3 b = static_cast<Arr3>(p);
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I am pretty sure I could use a `reinterpret_cast`, but is that really my only option here? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I could be wrong, but isn't Arr3 a ** type? IE a pointer to an array, which decays to a pointer? While p is just a pointer to the first element of an array.

Comment: You might want to explain what you're trying to do, a pointer to array can't be cast from a pointer to its contained type. Don't let the fact that arrays are implicitly converted to a pointer to their contained type at the drop of a hat confuse you, they aren't interchangeable.

Comment: @DominicMcDonnell No. `Arr3` is a pointer to an `int[3]` array. No array decaying takes place.

Comment: What's confusing about the message? This is an illegal conversion. Simply don't attempt it.

Comment: I'm using an internal company library that expects a pointer to a fixed-length array. There's not much to explain.

Comment: Then pass a pointer.

Comment: You can static_cast to void * and then to Arr3, but this is the same as reintepret_cast

Comment: Fixing your alias (`typedef int Arr3[3];`) would be a good start. A pointer to `int[3]` and a pointer are `int` are incompatible, end of story.

Comment: The memory layout of int[3] is compatible with int*, so I don't see why it's not possible without `reinterpret_cast`. For example, this code works http://ideone.com/lhzaqj

Comment: Thanks @zenith. So it's still not equivalent to int**, but could you use int** for the same purpose as Arr3?

Comment: @rlbond: (a) `int[3]` and `int(*)[3]` are not the same thing. (b) The memory layout of `int[3]` is _completely different_ to the memory layout of `int*`. You are confused.

Comment: I am aware of (a). `int(*)[3]` is a pointer to `int[3]`. The elements of an `int[3]` can be iterated over with an `int*`. In what way are the memory layouts *completely different*?

Comment: a pointer to an int[3] is the size of a pointer. An int[3] is the size of 3 ints.

Comment: @Cogwheel so? I want to convert a `int*` to `int (*)[3]`. Both are the size of a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't exactly `static_cast` here, but there is a trick that’s more type-safe than `reinterpret_cast`:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

typedef int (*arr3p)[3];
typedef int arr3[3];

inline arr3& to_arr3(arr3 p)
{
  return *(arr3p)(p);
}

inline arr3p to_arr3p(arr3 p)
{
  return (arr3p)(p);
}

int main() {
  arr3 a = {1, 2, 3};
  int *p = &a[0];

  arr3p foo = &to_arr3(p);
  cout << (*foo)[0] << ", ";

  arr3p bar = to_arr3p(p);
  cout << (*bar)[1] << ", ";

  arr3& baz = to_arr3(p);
  cout << baz[2] << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your cast is incorrect

```
Arr3 b = static_cast<Arr3>(p);
```

should be

```
Arr3 b = static_cast<Arr3>(&a);
```

In fact, the cast is unnecessary. Simply

```
 Arr3 b = &a;
```

will do.

Comment: @rlbond, then I believe the line `Arr3 b = static_cast<Arr3>(p);` needs to be `Arr3 b = static_cast<Arr3>(&p);`

Comment: That's not correct at all. There's no way that `int**` could be converted to `int(*)[3]`.

Answer (score -1):

One-dimension array is compatible with pointer, but that's not true for multi-dimension array. For example,

```
 int *p = (int*)1;
 int (*s)[3] = (int (*)[3])2;
 printf("%d,%d\n", sizeof(int*), sizeof(int (*)[3]));
 printf("%d,%d\n", ++p,++s);
```

The output is:

```
8,8
5,14
```

They are both pointer type, so their size is 8 bytes int 64-bit machine.`++s`, this array pointer will advance 3 elements, but `++p`, p will only advance 1 element. When we declare pointer array, we must specify size in every dimension except 1th dimension. The compiler needs to known that information to compute pointer arithmetic operation.